# Task gets repeated in firestore when querying documents

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem in querying documents in firestore. It evaluates the task 2 times which saves the document id in the ArrayList in duplicates.

```
   public void setMessageCount(final TextView txtComments) {
        userColelction.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()){
                        userIds.add(doc.getId());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please add your database structure, to see the issue more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult().getDocuments()){
userIds.add(doc.getId())
}
```